# Hibernate: UserType vs field/property access

Tags: java, hibernate

In the book `Java Persistence with Hibernate`, it discusses the following use case for using a `UserType`:

We need to store monetary amount in DB, but users can use any currency for it. So we 'normalize' the amount to USD before storing it in DB, and use a `UserType` implementation that will convert the amount to USD before storing, and to a user specified currency after reading it from DB but before giving it back to a user.

I can think of two other approaches to do this:

1) use field access for Hibernate for storing/reading from DB, and use public getter/setter for the conversion,

2) create a pair of private getter/setter for Hibernate which will use USD, and a public getter/setter for the necessary conversion for a user.

How do these approaches compare with using `UserType`? Are there any other advantages to `UserType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb I would say that `UserType` is appropriate for rather technical concerns while code in your model should focus on the domain concerns.

Imo [User Types in Hibernate](http://i-proving.com/2005/08/03/user-types-in-hibernate/) shows some good examples for technical conversion concerns like int-to-Date and so on which are well placed inside a `UserType`.

Concerning the currency example you gave I would say it strongly depends on the concrete scenario if a `UserType` is approriate. Currency conversion issues might become very complex and I would rather think these are domain concerns and so place according code in the model and not bury it in a `UserType`.

Possible drawback of the `UserType` in above example:

- It misses the dynamic nature of conversion rates. Consider a banking application: When I have an account balance of 75€ I actually have that amount in € and not the € amount converted to $ at a given point in time. When the €-to-$ rate falls I will have less $ and the other way round.

Possible advantage:

- You can easily run comparisons on query level like find the record with the highest/lowest amount.

Comment: But even technical concerns could be taken care of without using a UserType (through the approaches I mentioned above); or is there some problem that can be solved only through a UserType?

Comment: @shrini1000 Considering the plain DB-to-type conversion I can't imagine a case where it is completely impossible to do it the one or the other way. Think it really depends on the broader context which version is more appropriate and serves your needs best.

Answer (score 1):

Book examples are usually poor. Not that the book itself is poor. I, for instance, think that Java Persistence with Hibernate is the best Hibernate book out there. But the examples have to be concise and self-contained, so, a bit far from the real world.

If I remember correctly, this example serves only to demonstrate how to use a UserType, and it shows a lot of the features for it (specially the "reading back" part). The use-case itself is not important. So, I'd totally abstract the use case they presented.

For this particular scenario, if you ever need to store currencies in your database, I'd recommend taking a look at [Joda Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/userguide.html). They provide some ready-to-use JPA user types, so you don't need to worry about it. And yes, doing real-time conversion between currencies is not something you want to keep in your JPA entity. I'd have an EJB service to do that.

Comment: +1 for the comment on the example and a ref to Joda Money. Thx!